# Sending and receiving messages using Bluetooth sockets in C

Tags: c, windows, sockets, bluetooth

I am working on a Windows application that when launches starts a BT / SPP (RFCOMM) connection to a device, and then continuously receives and sends data.

So far I have been able to detect the device and to use socket() and connect() to start the connection and I am able to send data using send(). However I am not able to receive any data.

When I connect I use the SerialPortServiceClass_UUID GUID with port = 0.

Out of all the methods I have tried the one that I think should make most sense is to use recv() with the same socket used to open the connection. Alternatively I tried installing a service etc. and nothing worked.

All the examples that I googled only have one-way communication, so I am now wondering if 2-way communication is supposed to work or am I missing something?

Thank you for the help!!!

Comment: What libraries are you using? Are you using a Bluetooth dongle connected to a serial port on your computer?

Comment: I am using the regular Windows stack on a Dell Win10 tablet with built-in BT.